# How can I make a Swift 3.0 timer that calculates in hh:mm:ss:ms

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift3, selector

I followed DuncanC's solution in [Swift timer in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983111/swift-timer-in-milliseconds). Code below:

```
startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.02,
                                           target: self,
                                           selector: Selector(("advanceTimer:")),
                                           userInfo: nil,
                                           repeats: true)


func advanceTimer(timer: Timer)
{
    //Total time since timer started, in seconds
    self.time = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime
    //The rest of your code goes here
}
```

Xcode recommended I change `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()` to `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` and `startTime: NSTimeInterval` to `startTime: TimeInterval` for Swift 3.0.
My code produces the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyGame.GameScene advanceTimer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Why are you using `NSDate` instead of `Date`?

Comment: thanks for the correction. I managed to get the formatting from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872450/conversion-from-nstimeinterval-to-hour-minutes-seconds-milliseconds-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 `Selector` syntax is changed, now you need to pass first parameter label with your action, your `selector` should be like `#selector(self.advanceTimer(timer:))`.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.02,
                     target: self,
                     selector: #selector(self.advanceTimer(timer:)),
                     userInfo: nil,
                     repeats: true)
```

Comment: You've posted a similar answer several times. You really should be closing these questions as duplicates.

Comment: @rmaddy Next time i will sure raise flag.:)

Answer (score 1):

`advanceTimer(timer:)` should be declared differently according to [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), You should use Swift's native `Date` instead of `NSDate` and selector syntax has changed so your code would now be written like this:

```
startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.02,
                     target: self,
                     selector: #selector(advanceTimer),
                     userInfo: nil,
                     repeats: true)

func advanceTimer(_ timer: Timer)
{
    //Total time since timer started, in seconds
    self.time = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime
    //The rest of your code goes here
}
```

Also, `Timer` has new closure based methods, so your the whole thing can now be reduced to:

```
startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { timer in
    //Total time since timer started, in seconds
    self.time = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime
    //The rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: +1 for the new closure-based timers. I wish Apple had added that in iOS 4, when they first introduced blocks. Not sure why it took so long. I didn't discover this addition until a few days ago. (Note that if your app needs to run on iOS versions before iOS 10 then you can't use closure-based timers. :(